# How to only load text contents into JTextPane that are within the <body> tags?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, reader

Right now, I have a `JTextPane` in `Java Swing` that loads contents from a file into the pane. However, it loads everything including all the tags. I would like it to only load the contents. Is there a way to get to the tag and load the portion in between `<body>` and `</body>`?

Here is the code

```
public class LoadContent {

String path = "../WordProcessor_MadeInSwing/backups/testDir/cool_COPY3.rtf";

public void load(JTextPane jTextPane){
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        jTextPane.read(reader, path);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){

    }
}

}
```

If my `.rtf` file contains the word "Here is a test", it will load as:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      <!--
        p.default {
          family:Dialog;
          size:3;
          bold:normal;
          italic:;
          foreground:#333333;
        }
      -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #333333; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Dialog">
        Here is a test
      </span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I only want it to load "Here is a test"

Comment: There is nothing that I know of in the _Swing_ API that can do what you want. Since you are dealing with HTML, I think a HTML parser is what you need in order to extract the parts of the HTML text that you want. [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is a java HTML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like it to only load the contents

Then you need to parse out the contents first before displaying the text.

Here is a simple example to display the text between the `Span` tags:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

class GetSpan
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        // Create a reader on the HTML content

        Reader reader = getReader( args[0] );

        // Parse the HTML

        EditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)kit.createDefaultDocument();
        doc.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", Boolean.TRUE);
        kit.read(reader, doc, 0);

        // Find all the Span elements in the HTML document

        HTMLDocument.Iterator it = doc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.SPAN);

        while (it.isValid())
        {
            int start = it.getStartOffset();
            int end = it.getEndOffset();
            String text = doc.getText(start, end - start);
            System.out.println(  text );
            it.next();
        }
    }

    // If 'uri' begins with "http:" treat as a URL,
    // otherwise, treat as a local file.
    static Reader getReader(String uri)
        throws IOException
    {
        // Retrieve from Internet.
        if (uri.startsWith("http"))
        {
            URLConnection conn = new URL(uri).openConnection();
            return new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        }
        // Retrieve from file.
        else
        {
            return new FileReader(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Just run the class with your file as the parameter.

Edit:

Just noticed the question has been changed to look for text in the `<body>` tag instead of the `<span>` tag. For some reason an iterator is not returned for the `<body>` tag.

So another option is to use a `ParserCallback`. The callback will notify you every time a starting tag (or ending tag) is found, or when text of any tag is found.

A basic example would be:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class ParserCallbackText extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback
{
    private boolean isBody = false;

    public void handleText(char[] data, int pos)
    {
        if (isBody)
            System.out.println( data );
    }

    public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag tag, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos)
    {
        if (tag.equals(HTML.Tag.BODY))
        {
            isBody = true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        Reader reader = getReader(args[0]);
        ParserCallbackText parser = new ParserCallbackText();
        new ParserDelegator().parse(reader, parser, true);
    }

    static Reader getReader(String uri)
        throws IOException
    {
        // Retrieve from Internet.
        if (uri.startsWith("http"))
        {
            URLConnection conn = new URL(uri).openConnection();
            return new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        }
        // Retrieve from file.
        else
        {
            return new FileReader(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

The above example will ignore any text found the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a HTML parser. [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is nice one and very easy to use.

```
  public static String extractText(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
    }
    String textOnly = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString()).text();
    return textOnly;
  }
```